# Call a function without argument, although it needs one [K&R-C]

Tags: c

It's K&R-C and here is the code: http://v6shell.org/history/if.c

Look at the main-Method. There is this line "if(exp())".

But the function exp is declared as: exp(s). So it needs an argument.

**Why does this work? And why would you do this?**

Comment: compiler gives an error "too few arguments to function exp()"...! i am compiling using g++ compiler...

Comment: @Madan: Using G++ on (ancient) C code isn't a very precise test.

Comment: thank you for remembering about this..:)

Comment: This is undefined behavior according to the C89 standard. I don't know about K&R C though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimately, it is a bug in the Unix V6 shell support command, `if`.

The code for the function is:

```
exp(s) {
    int p1; 

    p1 = e1();
    if (eq(nxtarg(), "-o")) return(p1 | exp());
    ap--;
    return(p1);
}
```

The function parameter `s`, implicitly of type `int` (as is the function iteself), is actually unused in the function, so the bug is the presence of `s`, not the absence of an argument in the calls to `exp()`.  All the calls with zero actual arguments are correct.

Comment: So I could call a function with as many arguments I want, if the called function does not use any of these arguments there will be no problem?

Comment: @Kevin: sorta, but it is wasteful to pass arguments that won't be used.  However, it is the origin of the different calling conventions for functions in C on MS Windows.  Because the C function doesn't know how many arguments were passed, it can't generate the stack cleanup code for its call, unlike (say) a Pascal function.  So, the stack has to be reinstated by code in the calling functions (meaning the cleanup is written out every time the function is called), rather than inside the function itself (which would mean the cleanup is written out just once).

Comment: Do you have any source for the "C function doesn't know how many arguments were passed" or what alex said ""It doesn't even require function parameters to be checked.""? Where can I read this? Any wikipedia or article?

Comment: @Kevin: I responded to that as a comment to the main question.  You can find the [Unix 7th Edition manuals](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/) online.  Read the articles in Vol 2 about C.  Read K&R 1st Edition.  Read "C Traps and Pitfalls".  Read K&P'The UNIX Programming Environment".  Read any C book pre-dating the 1989 standard.  It was well known as an issue.  Probably read the C standard rationale too; function prototypes were the biggest and by far the most important innovation of C89/C90.

Comment: @Kevin: Note that this was a laxness in the compiler; things went horribly wrong if you made mistakes, but the compiler was not empowered to diagnose that you'd made mistakes.

Comment: Did the compiler have any name? Because I need to explain this code and I also need to explain why it was possible to call a function without a needed parameter. So if I say "All the calls with zero actual arguments are correct." or "It doesn't even require function parameters to be checked." I will need to add a relieable source. Is there any internet link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68039/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-kevin).

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the definition:

```
exp(s) {
    int p1;

    p1 = e1();

    if (eq(nxtarg(), "-o")) return(p1 | exp());
        ap--;

    return(p1);
}
```

1. `s` is not used
2. C doesn't require compile time type checking. It doesn't even require function parameters to be checked. Everything is a/series of bytes

Why does C not do any of those checks? From what I hear it's 'cause during first few years of C, computers were fairly weak. Doing those checks would require multiple passes to scan the source code, which basically increases compile time by a magnitude of n passes. So it just does a single pass, and takes every name as is, which is why function overloading is not supported

So if the definitions did make use of `s` in some way, you would most likely get some horrible runtime error with wonderful outputs to the console

Comment: Do you have any **source** for "It doesn't even require function parameters to be checked."?

Comment: Kevin: note that the Unix V6 shell was written prior to 1978 (I'd guess circa 1976).  That's before even the first edition of K&R was published. At the time, C-with-Classes, which became C++, was still in the distant future; prototypes simply didn't exist.  Functions could be declared before use — but declaration was only necessary if the return type was not `int`.  By comparison with modern C (meaning C99 or later) or with C++, the rules (or lack thereof) were anarchic.  But the machines were tiny by modern standards — big machines might have had 1 megabyte (yes, MiB, not GiB) of main memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in c

The compiler will not be able to perform compile-time checking of argument types and arity when the function is applied to some arguments. This can cause problems

Calling an undeclared function is poor style in C (See this) and **illegal in C++**

for example-

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int x); 

int main()
{
   f(); /* Poor style in C, invalid in C++*/
   getchar();
   return 0;
}

void f(int x)
{ 
   printf("%d", x);
}
```

This program will work but shouldn't be used.See this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype#Uses) link for more.

Comment: citation needed for your quote.

Comment: @rpattiso the link i was having is now dead :/

Comment: In this case they are calling the function using `f()`, which is more dodgy. Your answer does not answer the real issue, which is calling a function with less arguments than its definition accepts.

Comment: @rpattiso added wiki link for my quote :)

Comment: Strict compliance to the old C99 standard or the current C11 standard requires functions to be declared before they are used.  Pre-standard code (and the Unix v6 shell is pre-K&R 1st Edition, let alone pre-standard-C) doesn't worry about that — by design, did not need to worry about that.  The `lint` program provided some argument checking for functions; it was valuable in the days before C supported prototype function declarations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please check wiki link its clearly written that "This feature was removed from the C99 standard, thus omission of a function prototype will result in a compile error."

Comment: Yes, but the Unix V6 Shell was written circa 1976, before K&R 1st Edition.  It is an historical artefact, not a piece of modern C code.  It should be judged by the capabilities of C that prevailed when it was written, not by what can be written nowadays.