# Why would you return(0*ap++)?

Tags: c

It's K&R-C and here is the whole code: http://v6shell.org/history/if.c

Look at this function:

```
char *nxtarg() {
    if (ap>ac) return(0*ap++);
    return(av[ap++]);
}
```

**1.Question:** 
Why return (0*ap++)? Okay you want to return 0 and increase ap by 1. But why like this? Is it faster than `if (ap>ac) {ap++; return 0;}`?

**2.Question:** The return type of nxtarg has to be **char***, why can you return 0, an integer?

Comment: Please split your question in two. Since there is already an answer to the first one, I'd suggest that you withdraw the second.

Comment: (Because you have horrendous coding style?) Seriously, don't do that.

Comment: The code you have decided to look at for some reason is a very poor example of modern C practice, even if it is of historical interest. You could ask a question for each and every function in that file and not learn anything useful in the process. Or you could find better code to read. I would recommend the source code of musl: http://www.musl-libc.org

Comment: @PascalCuoq: "*ask a question for each and every function in that file*" - It appears that the OP is doing exactly that ;)

Comment: I notice it's also relying on the fact that argv[argc] is guaranteed to be NULL. That's an unusual feature of the arguments passed to main() and not something to actually rely on.

Comment: @Pascal&Oliver I ask because I need to explain the whole code. I am not doing this for fun :P

Comment: Bad luck Kevin. That code is so bad Schildt could have written it.

Comment: @DanAllen - it's perfectly reasonable to assume that `argv[argc] == NULL`, the standard guarantees it!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Absolutely. But when the resolution is `if(ap>=ac)` over `if(ap>ac)` why rely on slightly obscure facts that might fail later if for example the arguments are copied elsewhere for some reason?

Comment: You see code tricks like this `0*` thing all the time in APL as a way to put multiple statements in one line while still getting right-to-left evaluation.  In C, though, the only rationalization I can see is that it made the source code more compact.

Comment: @DanAllen: Ah, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: If this was about compressing the code into the fewest bytes possible, a clearer and shorter expression would have used the comma operator and done away with the parentheses (a `return` is not a function call!): `return ap++,0;`. The intent to discard the result `a++` is made (more) clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a little trick to squeeze the increment into a statement that returns zero. It is logically equivalent to a conditional

```
if (ap > ac) {
    ap++;
    return 0;
}
```

or even better with a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
return (ap++, (char *)0); // Thanks, Jonathan Leffler
```

Note that since zero in your example is not a compile-time constant, the expression needs a cast to be compliant with the standard:

```
if (ap>ac) return (char*)(0*ap++);
```

As far as returning an integer zero goes, it is considered to be equal to `NULL` pointer when used in pointer context.

Comment: This isn't a NULL pointer because `0*ap++` isn't a constant expression. The conversion in OP's code requires a cast in standard C. The code provided in this answer, on the other hand, is strictly conforming.

Comment: @mafso Thank you very much for the comment! I edited the answer to reflect the point about the required conversion. Thanks!

Comment: Even with the cast, I'm not sure the behaviour is well-defined (although I'm sure it works fine in practice).

Comment: An alternative rewrite would be `return (ap++, 0);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the comment, the solution with the comma operator is *much* better indeed.

Comment: I'm having a protracted discussion with @Kevin in response to [Call a function without argument although it needs one (K&R C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733348/call-a-function-without-argument-although-it-needs-one-kr-c/27733464#27733464) — this is the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68039/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-kevin) URL.  I note that the V6 shell dates from about 1976, before K&R 1st Edition.  It is really old code!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: It's implementation-defined, I think. On a platform where a null pointer isn't all bits zero, the distinction between a constant integer expression with value 0 used in a pointer context, and some other 0-valued integer expression could make sense; `(void *)(0,0) == 0` can be false on a conforming implementation, I think. (But I think, this is out of the scope of this question.)

Comment: I observe that GCC (4.9.2 tested), objects to `return (ap++, 0);` with 'return makes pointer from integer without a cast'.  On Linux, this can be fixed by using NULL (`#define NULL ((void *)0)`) or by adding a `(char *)` cast before the 0.  'Tis curious because a simple `return 0;` works fine; it isn't 100% obvious to me why the expression gets a warning and the simple return does not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's the same reason as with `0*ap++`; an expression using the comma operator is not a constant expression. For a non-constant zero, the cast is required, yielding an implementation-defined result (which isn't necessarily a null pointer, I think).

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator will increment the value, and return the value before it was incremented. If the function was supposed to return a pointer, you can return zero or `NULL`, to indicate a `NULL` pointer.