# Why would you increment here?

Tags: c, unix, return, increment

The function is from here: http://v6shell.org/history/if.c

Or with Syntax-Highlighting: http://pastebin.com/bj0Hvfrw

```
char *nxtarg() {

    if (ap>ac) return(0*ap++);
    return(av[ap++]);
}
```

This is the function that returns the next argument. ac is the number of arguments in argv and ap is the index of the current argument.

So I think with `if ( ap > ac )` we are testing, if there are any more arguments. And here comes my question:

**Why would you increment ap [ return( 0 * ap++ ) ], if ap is already bigger than ac, and therefore no more arguments?**

I would just return(0). **What problem will there be if I just return(0)?** Can you give me an example?

Notice that this is old K&R-C.

Comment: Maybe it will be used later and this is an indication that the array was already iterated.

Comment: There are `ap--` scattered all over that code. Presumably it all works together.

Comment: Notice that ap is a global variable used by different functions.

Comment: See also [Call a function without argument although it needs one (K&R C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733348/) and [Why would you `return (0 * ap++);`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734069/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places in the file which look like this:

```
if (eq(nxtarg(), "!"))
    return(!e3());
ap--;
```

Pseudo-code:

```
if nxtarg returns some string { do something }
else    // nxtarg returns 0 or another string
{
    // probably they want to test the same argument against another string
    ap--; 
}
```

To make this possible, they increment `ap` in any case.

As requested, this is the caller code in the case `nxtarg` does not increment `ap` returning 0:

```
char* p = nxtarg();
if ( p != 0 ) 
{
    if (eq(p, "!")) return(!e3());
    ap--;
}
// p == 0 - don't decrement ap
```

Comment: What problem will there be, if I just return(0), instead of return(0*ap++)? Do you have an example?

Comment: In this case `ap` value will be different, when `nextarg` returns 0 or not, and caller code should be different as well. They want to decrement `ap` in the case of any undesired result.

Comment: Right! Thank you Alex :)